# Eclipse Makefile Error

Tags: eclipse, makefile

I need some help with solving an error. I was trying to create a simple bluetooth server using the library bluez-5.31 . I am using eclipse on Raspbian Jessie which is similar to Debian but I have little to no experience with either one. I tried fixing it for a couple days now and nothing seems to be working so i really need some help...
This is the error description:

```
error 1:    make:*** [Bluetooth Server 2]Error 1                Resource:   Bluetooth Server 2      
error 2:    recipe for target 'Bluetooth Server 2' failed       Resource: makefile                  Path: /Bluetooth Server 2/Debug     Location: line 45

where "Bluetooth Server 2" is the name of the project[/code]
```

This is main:

```
#include "/usr/include/stdint.h"
#include "/usr/include/bluez-5.31/lib/bluetooth.h"
#include "/usr/include/bluez-5.31/lib/hci.h"
#include "/usr/include/bluez-5.31/lib/hci_lib.h"
#include "/usr/include/bluez-5.31/lib/rfcomm.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_rc loc_addr = { 0 }, rem_addr = { 0 };
    char buf[1024] = { 0 };
    int s, client, bytes_read;
    unsigned int opt = sizeof(rem_addr);

    //allocate socket
    s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

    //bind socket to port 1 of the first available adapter

    bdaddr_t tmp = {0,0,0,0,0,0};

    loc_addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    loc_addr.rc_bdaddr = tmp;
    loc_addr.rc_channel = 1;
    bind(s, (struct sockaddr* )&loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr));

    //put socket into listening mode
    listen(s, 1);

    //accept one connection
    client = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_addr, &opt);

    ba2str( &rem_addr.rc_bdaddr, buf );
    fprintf( stderr, "accepter connection from %s\n", buf);
    memset( buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

    //read data from the client
    bytes_read = recv(client, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    if( bytes_read > 0 )
    {
        printf("received [%s]\n", buf);
    }

    //close connection
    //close(client);
    //close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the make file:
    -include ../makefile.init

```
RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include src/subdir.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(C++_DEPS)),)
-include $(C++_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPP_DEPS)),)
-include $(CPP_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CXX_DEPS)),)
-include $(CXX_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build     variables 

# All Target
all: Bluetooth\ Server\ 2

# Tool invocations
Bluetooth\ Server\ 2: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Linker'
    g++ -L/usr/include/ -bluez-5.31 -o "Bluetooth Server 2" $(OBJS)         $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM)     $(OBJS)$(C++_DEPS)$(C_DEPS)$(CC_DEPS)$(CPP_DEPS)$(EXECUTABLES)$(CXX_DEPS)$(C_U    PPER_DEPS) "Bluetooth Server 2"
    -@echo ' '

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

And this is what changes i made to project properties:

```
- C/C++ Build >> Settings >> Tool Settings >> GCC C++ Linker >>     Miscellaneous: In the linker flags box i wrote: "-bluez-5.31"
- C/C++ Build >> Settings >> Tool Settings >> GCC C++ Linker >> Libraries:     Added " "bluez-5.31" " in -l
- C/C++ Build >> Settings >> Tool Settings >> GCC C++ Linker >> Libraries:     Added " /usr/include " in -L
```

Comment: Are there some compiler error messages appearing before these make errors?

Comment: Don't use whitespaces in identifiers or names, or even file names. That makes it quite hard to work with them, for example you had to escape them in the Makefile target name. It appears that it would be a lot simple to write a Makefile by hand and use a simple text editor. Unless it's really helpful, don't use complicated IDEs like eclipse. Use *geany* and Makefiles for small projects and you will learn a lot of how that works, and you will be very happy with the gained simplicity. Also, eclipse is a really complicated IDE.

Comment: There are no other errors. Only the two are appearing.

Comment: As it turns out, the white space in the project name was the problem. Made a new project which didn't have any white spaces and the errors were not there anymore.